# How to disable intent redirecting the current activity to the same activity in android menu listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am building an android app.I have made the listview menu.One of the options is profile page.When i click on the profile button on the listview,the activity is sent to the profile activity.But after starting the profile activity,again if i click the profile button in the listview menu,the profile activity again starts.How to disable this?

Thanks for your time.

The code is as follow.Its simple intent starting.

```
 //setting onclick listener on the menu items
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            if(position == 8){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),Chat.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(position == 7){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),SaleAndRentList.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(position == 1){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),FriendsList.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(position == 0){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),Profile.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(position == 6){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),CountryStudentList.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(position == 5){
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),UnivStudentList.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the previously selected position in a Singleton class for example. When you click the button again, check if the previous position is the same with the selected one.

Comment: Ok i did the way that you told me to.It is working well.But if i come back to an activity using back button of the phone,the property of the single ton class is still having the previous position value even though the position of the current activity is changed

Comment: When loading each and every activity ( onCreate() ) update the value in the Singleton with the value corresponding to the current activity.

Comment: dont know where are my brains today.Thanks for your time